# Verify and critique writing: $f$ is continuous if and only if the preimage under $f$ of any open set is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, proof-writing

Show $f: D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous if and only if the preimage under $f$ of any open set is open.  (By *continuous*, we mean the $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition: for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - a| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$.)

*Note: Proofs are readily available; this questions asks to verify and critique* my *proof and its writing*.

**Proof:** Let $f$ be a continuous function and $A$ an arbitrary open set, with $f^{-1}(A)$ its preimage.  We claim that for any $x \in f^{-1}(A)$, there exists $B(x) \subseteq f^{-1}(A)$.  For all $x \in f^{-1}(A), f(x) \in A$, and since $A$ is open, there must exist $B_\varepsilon(f(x)) \subseteq A$.  Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $f(B_\delta(X)) \subseteq B_\varepsilon(f(x))$. Hence, $B_\delta(x) \subseteq f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(A)$ is open.

Conversely, let $f$ be a function such that if a set is open than its preimage under $f$ is open as well.  Let $x$ be an arbitrary point in the domain of $f$.  For any $\varepsilon > 0$, let $A = B_\varepsilon(f(x))$.  Since $A$ is open, $f^{-1}(A)$ is open as well, and since $x \in f^{-1}(A)$, there exists $B_\delta(x) \subseteq f^{-1}(A)$.  Thus, $f(B_\delta(x)) \subseteq A = B_\varepsilon(f(x))$, and $f$ is continuous.

**Questions:**

1. Is this proof correct? Rigorous?
2. Is it well written? Could the writing be improved?
3. Are there other approaches I should have considered?

Comment: You would want to state the definition of continuous, since sometimes that's taken as the definition.

Comment: @DavidLui AdamRubinson Thanks, definition of continuous and domain and range of $f$ added.

Comment: I think your proof is correct. Just avoid "there exists $B(x)$" or "there exists $B_\delta(x)$". Prefer "there exists $\delta>0$".

Comment: @AnneBauval You write "avoid 'there exists $B(x)$'... prefer 'there exists $\delta > 0$'".  Why is that? I expected the first is preferred, since the concept of $\delta > 0$ is well known, having to repeat it just distracts from the proof.  Why do you recommend spelling it out?

Comment: We all *guess* what "there exists $B(x)$" *suggests* but formally it means nothing. Better say "there exists an open ball centered at $x$". As for "there exists $B_\delta(x)$", it is a little better but since you asked for criticism on rigor: one should not quantify ($\forall$ or $\exists$) over an object *depending on* $\delta$, but rather quantify directly on $\delta.$

Comment: I agree with Anne Bauval. Your proof is good, but your write-up can be improved. If you are trying to prove continuity, then you need state your case per the definition of continuity, or per some specific theorem you are going to use to prove continuity. That definition is "for each $\epsilon$, there is a $\delta$", not "for each $B(f(x))$ there is a $B_\delta(x)$". Instead you force that conversion on your reader. In this case, it is a fairly trivial translation, but it is still bad practice. Your job is to convince your reader. The more you leave to them, the fewer who will be convinced.

Comment: Coming at this with a 'beginner's mind', you assume that the reader knows that $\;B_\gamma(x) = \left\{y \mid \left| x-y \right| < \gamma\right\}\;$ is a 'ball'; "Hence" hides an appeal to the previous $\;B_\varepsilon(f(x)) \subseteq A\;$ and transitivity, followed by $\;f(\ldots) \subseteq A \;\Leftrightarrow\; \ldots \subseteq f^{-1}(A)\;$; and "since $x \in f^{-1}(A)$" is also not immediately obvious: it is equivalent to $\;f(x) \in A\;$ which follows from your choice of $\;A\;$.  So those few words and symbols keep a lot of things implicit, which makes the proof harder to read.